# Performance optimization processing 95,000+ NetCDF files (using xarray + dask)

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, geospatial

I was told over at gis.stackexchange.com that this question would be a better fit here.

I already have a working code but it is very slow and my hunch is that it could be optimized. *The goal here is to process 11 years of data = 11 x 12 x 30 x 24 = roughly 95,040 hourly files*

On a RAID/NAS external storage I have NetCDF files from NLDAS-2 products that look like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (lon: 464, lat: 224, time: 1, bnds: 2)
Coordinates:
  * lon          (lon) float32 -124.9 -124.8 -124.7 ... -67.31 -67.19 -67.06
  * lat          (lat) float32 25.06 25.19 25.31 25.44 ... 52.69 52.81 52.94
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 1992-11-09T15:00:00
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    time_bnds    (time, bnds) datetime64[ns] 1992-11-09T14:00:00 1992-11-09T1...
    Tair         (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    Qair         (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    PSurf        (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    Wind_E       (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    Wind_N       (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    LWdown       (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    CRainf_frac  (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    CAPE         (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    PotEvap      (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    Rainf        (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
    SWdown       (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
```

The files are hourly and I'm aggregating them on a daily basis. Here are the important steps of my code:

**Reading**

I'm reading the data in chunks of one month at a time.

```
forcing_data = xr.open_mfdataset(file_list, chunks={'time': 24}, 
                    parallel=False, combine='nested', concat_dim='time', 
                    autoclose=True)
```

I tried using `parallel=True` but with the files stored on a NAS I was getting reading errors different every time I re-ran the code.

I have a little validation step where I use the `time_bnds` variable to make sure I have the right time boundaries. I think this could be optimized when generating the files to read but I don't think it's the main problem here

```
idx_from, idx_to = get_time_indices_from_time_bnds(forcing_data, start_date, end_date)
forcing_data = forcing_data.isel(time=slice(idx_from, idx_to+1))
```

**Augmenting**

I need to generate new variables by performing arithmetic on the existing variables. This is pretty fast typically.

```
forcing_data['RH'] = compute_RH(forcing_data['PSurf'], forcing_data['Tair'], forcing_data['Qair'])
forcing_data['Tdew'] = compute_dew_point(forcing_data['RH'], forcing_data['Tair'])
forcing_data['wind_speed'] = compute_wind_speed(forcing_data['Wind_E'], forcing_data['Wind_N'])
forcing_data['wind_direction'] = compute_wind_direction(forcing_data['Wind_E'], forcing_data['Wind_N'])
```

**Aggregating (Main Loop)**

In a loop I aggregate the data month by month (I tried different time steps, it actually seemed like weekly/daily would work better in some cases) by reading the files in the way mentioned above

```
# get the files for each dataset type requested
    agg_list = []

    curr_date = start_date

    while curr_date < end_date:
        
        # Read the forcing data
        ds = read_forcing_dataset(files_dir, curr_date, one_month, product=product, augment=True)

        # Aggregate the forcing data
        agg = aggregate_forcing_data_daily(ds)

        # Force dask to compute
        agg = agg.compute()


        agg_list.append(agg)
        
        curr_date += one_month

    # Concatenate the aggregated data
    agg_ds = xr.concat(agg_list, dim='time')
```

The `aggregate_forcing_data_daily` function has a similar while loop with a day increment, it basically uses `agg_data = ds.isel(time=slice(idx_from, idx_to + 1)).map(agg_func, keep_attrs=True)` with `agg_func` returning `x.mean(dim='time')` or `x.sum(dim='time')` based on the `x.name`. It also adds the minimum and maximum temperature for that day in the following fashion:

```
agg_data['Tmin'] = ds['Tair'].sel(time=slice(start_date, end_date)).min(dim='time', skipna=True, keep_attrs=True)
agg_data['Tmax'] = ds['Tair'].sel(time=slice(start_date, end_date)).max(dim='time', skipna=True, keep_attrs=True)
```

**Performance so far:**

This part of the code takes about **5 to 6 minutes per month of data** on a laptop with Intel i9 @ 2.5 GHz and 32 GB of RAM, 4 processes (16 threads)

**Extracting time-series for specific coordinates**

```
for lat, lon in zip(lats,lons):
    df = agg_ds.sel(lat=lat, lon=lon, method='nearest').to_dataframe()
    df = function_to_rename_and_reorder_columns(df)

    df.to_parquet(custom/path/to/savefile/latlon.parquet)
```

**Performance for this step**

Before I used `agg = agg.compute()` in the aggregation loop, this step took a lot of time but now it seems to be much faster. Prior to that the `DataFrame` generation step took looooot of time, **many minutes if not hours**. As it is it would take over a day of non-stop computation to process the 11 years dataset. Is it just the way it has to be?

I tried to play with the chunk size and the timestep for reading files and monitoring with the dask dashboard but I haven't really been able to improve further.

Like I said at the beginning this works but it feels like it could be improved. I think that the fact that the files are stored on a NAS is not the best but I cannot get around that for now. This is my first big code involving `xarray` and NetCDF files so I might be missing obvious things.

Comment: https://www.coiled.io/blog/speed-up-pandas-query-10x-with-dask might help ? (just the dask stuff). Also, "CPU" is really "CPU + L1 cache + L2 cache + disk" -- is your disk SSD ? Also, do you really need all lon: 464, lat: 224 or could you subset say 1/10 of that early ?